# Can't make a syntax highligting work properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting

I have this code for formatting certain programmic keywords inside a WPF RichTextBox
i tried to loop on keyword in the richtextbox and change it's forecolor, but the selection works fine the first time, then it breaks down, I searched for this problem and they said the solution is to clear all the properties before selecting again

```
public void FormatTextBox()
    {
        TextRange fullText = new TextRange(txtCode.Document.ContentStart, txtCode.Document.ContentEnd);
        
        TextPointer OldSelectionStart = txtCode.Selection.Start;
        TextPointer OldSelectionEnd = txtCode.Selection.End;
        // getting keywords/functions
        string keywords = @"\b(public|private|partial|static|namespace|class|using|void|foreach|in)\b";
        MatchCollection keywordMatches = Regex.Matches(fullText.Text, keywords);

        // getting types/classes from the text 
        string types = @"\b(Console)\b";
        MatchCollection typeMatches = Regex.Matches(fullText.Text, types);

        // getting comments (inline or multiline)
        string comments = @"(\/\/.+?$|\/\*.+?\*\/)";
        MatchCollection commentMatches = Regex.Matches(fullText.Text, comments, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        // getting strings
        string strings = "\".+?\"";
        MatchCollection stringMatches = Regex.Matches(fullText.Text, strings);

        lbTitle.Focus();
        txtCode.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
        fullText.ClearAllProperties();
        
        
        foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)
        {
            txtCode.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
            fullText.ClearAllProperties();
            txtCode.Selection.Select(fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index), fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + m.Length));
            txtCode.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
        }

        foreach (Match m in typeMatches)
        {
            txtCode.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
            fullText.ClearAllProperties();
            txtCode.Selection.Select(fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index), fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + m.Length));
            txtCode.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkCyan);
            
        }

        foreach (Match m in commentMatches)
        {
            txtCode.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
            fullText.ClearAllProperties();
            txtCode.Selection.Select(fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index), fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + m.Length));
            txtCode.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
            
        }

        foreach (Match m in stringMatches)
        {
            txtCode.Selection.ClearAllProperties();
            fullText.ClearAllProperties();
            txtCode.Selection.Select(fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index), fullText.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + m.Length));
            txtCode.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Brown);
            
        }

        
        txtCode.Selection.Select(OldSelectionStart, OldSelectionEnd);
        txtCode.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);

        txtCode.Focus();
    }
```

the problem  seems that the loop format the word then clear the formatting of all words and format the second word and so on

**Edit:** I think it may have something with `ClearAllProperties()` Method

Comment: _"I think it may have something with `ClearAllProperties()`"_ - I think so too.  Try commenting out that line

Comment: yeah i did my code without it in the beganing, but without it the selection with the RichTextbox.Selection.Select Breaks down , and with it the formatting is cleared on each new loop,  this is the main problem for me